# Unable to setup k-9 mail (k-9-5.107) in android app?

Tags: android, email

I have integrated K-9 Mail third party(k-9-5.107) in my application. I have done integration process but my problem is that I am unable to configure my gmail account. I tried many times but every time I am getting issues like

1. Invalid email and password.
2. Cannot connect to server.
3. Failed Authentication.

I also referred following link setup process :
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/Manual-AccountSetup

Comment: Yeah! I also have this type of issues in my application. I have integrated k9-mail but getting same issues in configure my gmail account. I have wasted so much time on this issue but still didn't get solution....!